# JSP variables aren't interpreted

Tags: tomcat, cpanel

I tried to run a servlet or jsp page on a cPanel server. I don't know why the variable has been displayed on the web page instead of the real value.

```
<td><input id="uname" type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" size="30" value="${requestScope.user}"></td>
```

On the web page I see ${requestScope.user} instead of the user. How can I can get the real value ?

I tried this code, from an Internet example :

```
<%
String [] noises = {"Lion","Tiger","Cat"};
request.setAttribute("noises",noises);
%>
${requestScope.noises[0]}
${requestScope.noises["0"]}
${requestScope.noises['0']}
${noises[0]}
${noises["0"]}
${noises['0']} '
```

but it displays

${requestScope.noises[1]} ${requestScope.noises["0"]} ${requestScope.noises['0']} ${noises[0]} ${noises["0"]} ${noises['0']} **

Comment: Did you try this ?  <td><input id="uname" type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" size="30" value='<c:out var="${requestScope.user}" />'></td>

Comment: This gives to me an error : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /test.jsp(327,83) According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute value is mandatory for tag out

Comment: What is a cPanel server, does it support JSPs, and have you configured it correctly to do so? Does a simple "Hello, World" JSP where the "Hello, World" is in a JSP Expression run as expected?

Comment: Yes, the cPanel server support JSPs I made a test jsp page and it works, only this implicit objects don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td>

     <input id="uname" type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" size="30" value='<c:out value="${user}" />'>

</td>
```

Make sure you import the c tag. The import should look something like this -

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: This error : org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /test.jsp(327,83) According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute value is mandatory for tag out. Even if I added the <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

Comment: You probably did not copy it correctly. Did you use this tag   -   <c:out value="${user}" />